# Finding where an object in access is referenced

Tags: ms-access

I have an ancient database that I am trying to split. Whenever the process is finished, it will give me this error:

https://gyazo.com/eb35294d8d271d084a691454559e378e

Which translated means something along these lines: "Access' Database Engine can't find the object "ay_faltas". Make sure that the object exists and that the access path is listed correctly."

This is not an object in the database and I don't know how to find where the reference to the object is, so that I can delete it.

Comment: I suggest using a Search tool like [Find and Replace](http://www.rickworld.com/products.html#Find%20and%20Replace%209.0).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend free MS Access addon http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/
It allows to find all references mentioned in objects, modules, queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vb script I use to find all occurrences of a date and change it - you may be able to modify it to find your string

```
Function update()
Dim DB As Database
Dim QD As QueryDef
Dim S As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
For Each QD In DB.QueryDefs
    S = QD.SQL
    If InStr(S, "2009") > 0 Then
        S = Replace(S, "2009", "2010")
        QD.SQL = S
    End If
Next QD
MsgBox ("Done")
End Function
```

Alternatively, you can look at some (undocumented) system tables.  In the Navigation pane, look for Navigation options and turn on "Show system objects".  Two system tables may be helpful:

```
MSysObjects
ID links to ObjectID in MSysQueries
Name is the object name
Type - 1,4 and 6 are tables, 5 is a query


MSysQueries
ObjectID links to ID in MSysObjects (multiple rows for each ObjectID)
Attribute
  1 - query type
  5 - Source data for the query
Name1 field (for Attribute 5 rows) is the source table or query
Expression field (for Attribute 5 rows) is the select statement for a Union query
```

These 2 tables may help you find the term you're looking for.